# Building a Twitter Search Box With Search Suggestions

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

I am developing a site that is integrated with Twitter content and I would like to enhance my search box providing search suggestions for hashtags and handles as the user types. Is there any way to get this autocomplete data generated from Twitter?

```
thanks().InAdvance();
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in the Twitter API that does that. Besides, it wouldn't work either because the rate limits would never permit that type of interaction. e.g. you might have `n` queries in a 15 minute window. If you eat up that much rate limit, it leaves less to iterate through the rest of the results an support subsequent queries, leaving the user waiting until the next 15 minute window. I understand what you want to do, but 3rd party APIs, like Twitter, have very specific pre-defined functionality and don't work like a general purpose database.